Does increasing concentration of CO2 in water displace O2?
Does increasing the concentration of CO2 in water displace O2 that is already dissolved in water?
In fishkeeping, it is oft repeated that oversaturating your water with CO2 will suffocate your fish. I am trying to understand why this happens. The usual explanation is that CO2 will displace O2.
My hazy memory of chemistry is that different gases have different solubility levels from each other, so oversaturation of CO2 will not impact the solubility of O2. Am I misremembering this?

Too much CO2 kills by itself.

As you state, each gas acts independently (unless the gases react with each other, as would HCl and NH3 -- but that is not the case with CO2 and O2). CO2 also increases acidity of water. [BTW, people can detect CO2, but not O2, which makes anoxia a much more immediate danger than CO2 buildup. However, I'm not sure about goldfish. Sorry, I don't mean to carp, this was added just for the halibut.]

Read the phenomenon of sparging https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparging_(chemistry)

CO2 has its own strong biochemical impact.

So CO2 is bad for fish, but not because it displaces O2 in the water.
